# Using realloc() function in C for increasing column in 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, realloc

### I have the following code which must resize a column of matrix of 2D array:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

int n = 3;
int m = 4;
int * * mas = malloc(n * sizeof( * mas));

for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
  mas[i] = malloc(m * sizeof( * (mas[i])));
}
for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    mas[i][j] = i + 1;
    printf("%d ", mas[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
```

when I resize a column of matrix(but leave the same size of rows) it finish starting a loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
  int * tmp = realloc(mas[i], (m + 1) * sizeof( * mas[i]));
  if (tmp) {
    mas[i] = tmp;
  }
}

mas[1][4] = 100;
mas[2][4] = 200;
mas[3][4] = 300;

for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < m + 1; j++) {
    printf("%d ", mas[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
for(int i = 1; i< n+1; i++){
    free(mas[i]);
}
free(mas);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

---

```
  I have:
  2 2 2 2
  3 3 3 3
  4 4 4 4
```

---

### after printing this myprg.exe finished

but when I do resize with simple vector it've done!

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
int n = 3;
int m = 4;
int* mas = malloc(n*sizeof(mas));

for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++){
    mas[i] = 0;
}
for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++){
    printf("%d\n", mas[i]);
}
mas = realloc(mas, (n+2)*sizeof(*mas));
for(int i = 1; i < n+3; i++){
    mas[i] = 0;
}
for(int i = 1; i < n+3; i++){
     printf("%d\n", mas[i]);
}
free(mas);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

---

I think it's something with pointer of 2D array, but I don't understand what exactly :(

Comment: Detail: neither `int * * mas` nor `int * mas` are pointers to a 2D array.  `int (*mas)[n][m]` is a pointer to a 2D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace every `for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)` with `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` in your code. Array indices goes from `0` to `n-1` not `1` to `n`

Similarly, change

```
mas[1][4] = 100;
mas[2][4] = 200;
mas[3][4] = 300;
```

to

```
mas[0][4] = 100;
mas[1][4] = 200;
mas[2][4] = 300;
```

for the same reason.

It is better to check the return value of those `malloc`s as well to see if they were successful or not. Also, you should take proper action if the `realloc` failed and `tmp` is `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you!) It's working now but now I have a new pronblem for my university task, it would be better for me take a rows from 1 to 3 and columns from 0 to 9 im 2D matrix.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get you. Maybe change the value of `m` to 10? or 9 if you resize.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have not expressed correctly. This code I wrote for example because realloc() fails in my labouring code that have rows - 1 to 3 and colums - 0 to 8.

Comment: In addition, can you explaine why it didn't work for realloc(when rows 1 to 3) only when starting from 0?

Comment: Array indices start from zero. Similarly, Memory addresses start from zero. Why? All I can say is, it was designed that way.